# How to generate HTML block from code behinde in ASP.Net C# programmaticaly?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

This is my code :

Generate HTML From Code Behind

How I can generate HTML block with C# code and fill "Generate HTML From Code Behind" part

Thanks .

Comment: We need an example of what you have done so far.  As given, you are asking us to write the code for you.  Check out this link on creating an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript you can proceed..

In UI take Radiobuttonlist, In code behind write a method to get data from database, After that find the Radiobuttonlist from javascript and Bind the data.